# Assign and print an input string to a variable. Lisp

Tags: input, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, buffered

I want my program to ask for an expression, assign an inputted string to a variable 'exp' and then print the expression.

However I am having some trouble. I first tried using (read)

```
(princ "Enter a expression to be evaluated.")
(setf exp (read))
(princ exp)
```

However when i use this code, this happens.

```
Hello this is an expression            ;This is what I input
Enter a expression to be evaluated.HELLO
T
```

I then tried to use (read-line), but when I do this, I don't seem to be asked for an input at all.

```
(princ "Enter a expression to be evaluated.")
(setf exp (read-line))
(princ exp)
```

gets

```
Enter a expression to be evaluated.
T
```

The program just ends.

After some answers I have come up with this

```
(defun get-input (prompt)
  (clear-input)                     
  (write-string prompt)             
  (finish-output)                   
  (setf exp (read-line)))           

(get-input "Enter an expression: ")
(princ exp)
```

However when i run this the following happens

```
My first sentence                            ;My first input
Enter an expression: My second sentence      ;it then asks for input, i do so
My second sentence                           ;my second input is printed back at me
T
```

Comment: `exp` is undeclared. You need to declare variables in Common Lisp.

Comment: How do I declare it? I thought it was declared automatically.

Comment: `LET`, `LET*`, `DEFUN`, `LAMBDA`, `DEFVAR`, `DEFPARAMETER`, ...

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a FAQ.

Output can be buffered. Use `FINISH-OUTPUT` to make sure that the output has actually reached its destination.

`READ` reads Lisp s-expressions. It returns the corresponding data-structure. It's only useful when you enter a valid s-expression.

`READ-LINE` reads a line and returns a string.

Example:

```
* 
(defun ask (&optional (message "Input: "))
  (clear-input)           ; get rid of pending input
  (write-string message)  ;
  (finish-output)         ; make sure output gets visible
  (read-line))            ; read a line as a string

ASK
* (ask "Name: ")
Name: Rainer

"Rainer"
NIL
```

File `p.lisp`:

```
(defun get-input (prompt)
  (clear-input)
  (write-string prompt)
  (finish-output)
  (read-line))

(write-string (get-input "Enter a sentence: "))
(finish-output)
```

Output

```
* (load "/tmp/p.lisp")
Enter a sentence: foo is not a bar
foo is not a bar
T
```

Comment: What is wrong in my second piece of code so that it doesn't read anything when using read-line ? It just seems to read nothing and doesn't wait for the user to type anything

Comment: @sam: make sure that the output is printed. Use FINISH-OUTPUT. If there is pending input in the input stream, READ-LINE will read it and return immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing it right, I've tried using finish-output but  don't know if Im using it correctly, what is it meant to do? My program has the exact same issues.

Comment: This has helped a lot. There is ONE thing that's still broken though, when I run this, I have to input something and press enter before it then asks for the string. It then works as expected. But as I said, it first requires me to input something and press enter, this has no effect on the later output though.

Comment: @sam: You would need to show us the code and a reproducible test case.

Comment: I have added to the original question

Comment: @sam: you need to declare variables. Other than that I can't reproduce your problem. See my edit.